# Need to update if exist or insert the values

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to update the price of the brick if there is already a brick in the purchased table, else I have to insert it. I wrote this code:

```
DECLARE 
    colour VARCHAR2(10) :='brown';
    shape VARCHAR2(10) :='rectangle';
    price NUMBER(10,2) :=21;

BEGIN 
    UPDATE purchased_bricks pb
    SET pb.price = price
    WHERE pb.colour = colour
    AND pb.shape = shape;

    IF sql%rowcount = 0 
        THEN
        INSERT INTO purchased_bricks
        VALUES(colour,shape,price);
    END IF;
END;
```

The first time I ran it, the record was inserted. Then when I tried to update the price of the brick the change was not reflected in the table.

Comment: For future reference, Oracle has supported the MERGE statement since 9i. It is neater than PL/SQL and more efficient. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9017.htm#SQLRF01606)

Comment: i think update and insert both need to be inside if conditions. Above that you need to find whether brick exist or not and put it in if conditions.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of PL/SQL, I'd suggest **MERGE** which is also known as *UPSERT* (UPdate and/or inSERT).

Here's an example:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE purchased_bricks
  2  (
  3     colour   VARCHAR2 (10),
  4     shape    VARCHAR2 (20),
  5     price    NUMBER
  6  );

Table created.

SQL> MERGE INTO purchased_bricks p
  2       USING (SELECT 1 FROM DUAL) x
  3          ON (    p.colour = '&&par_colour'
  4              AND p.shape = '&&par_shape')
  5  WHEN MATCHED
  6  THEN
  7     UPDATE SET p.price = &&par_price
  8  WHEN NOT MATCHED
  9  THEN
 10     INSERT     (colour, shape, price)
 11         VALUES ( '&&par_colour', '&&par_shape', &&par_price);
Enter value for par_colour: brown
Enter value for par_shape: rectangular
Enter value for par_price: 21

1 row merged.

SQL> select * From purchased_bricks;

COLOUR     SHAPE                     PRICE
---------- -------------------- ----------
brown      rectangular                  21
```

Let's try a different price:

```
SQL> undefine par_price
SQL> MERGE INTO purchased_bricks p
  2       USING (SELECT 1 FROM DUAL) x
  3          ON (    p.colour = '&&par_colour'
  4              AND p.shape = '&&par_shape')
  5  WHEN MATCHED
  6  THEN
  7     UPDATE SET p.price = &&par_price
  8  WHEN NOT MATCHED
  9  THEN
 10     INSERT     (colour, shape, price)
 11         VALUES ( '&&par_colour', '&&par_shape', &&par_price);
Enter value for par_price: 50

1 row merged.

SQL> select * from purchased_bricks;

COLOUR     SHAPE                     PRICE
---------- -------------------- ----------
brown      rectangular                  50

SQL>
```

The above example is adjusted so that it works in SQL*Plus. Depending on tool you use, parameters' values might be referenced differently, such as

```
MERGE INTO purchased_bricks p
     USING (SELECT 1 FROM DUAL) x
        ON (    p.colour = :par_colour
            AND p.shape = :par_shape)
WHEN MATCHED
THEN
   UPDATE SET p.price = :par_price
WHEN NOT MATCHED
THEN
   INSERT     (colour, shape, price)
       VALUES ( :par_colour, :par_shape, :par_price);
```

Answer (score 2):

I found it. The problem was that the variable names were the same as the column names. So `set pb.price = price` updated the table with the existing table value not the variable value. The solution is to make the names  different, say by using a prefix.

```
DECLARE 
    l_colour VARCHAR2(10) :='brown';
    l_shape VARCHAR2(10) :='rectangle';
    l_price NUMBER(10,2) :=21;

BEGIN 
    UPDATE purchased_bricks pb
    SET pb.price = l_price          
    WHERE pb.colour = l_colour                
    AND pb.shape = l_shape;

    IF sql%rowcount = 0 
        THEN
        INSERT INTO purchased_bricks
        VALUES(colour,shape,price);
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Note that for a complete solution you need to change the names of **all** the variables, not just `price`. Otherwise your block will update every record in the table, for the same reason as it appeared to be updating zero records previously.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a count on your desired filter criteria and if it is greater than 0 than update it else insert the new row;something like below :

```
DECLARE 
        colour VARCHAR2(10) :='brown';
        shape VARCHAR2(10) :='rectangle';
        price NUMBER(10,2) :=21;
        count_row Number;

      BEGIN 
        Select count(*) into count_row from purchased_bricks pb
        WHERE pb.colour = colour
        AND pb.shape = shape;

        IF count_row > 0
        THEN
        UPDATE purchased_bricks pb
        SET pb.price = price
        WHERE pb.colour = colour
        AND pb.shape = shape;

         ELSE

            INSERT INTO purchased_bricks
            VALUES(colour,shape,price);
        END IF;
    END;
```

Comment: SELECT you wrote is invalid.